# Can emacs use gpg-agent in a terminal at all?

Tags: ssh, terminal, emacs, gpg

I understand that there are problems with getting `pinentry-curses` to work with emacs (see some of the comments on http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EasyPG), and so using emacs in a terminal isn't compatible with gpg-agent because of this.

I can't use a graphical pinentry tool in this case as this is over an ssh connection to a remote machine.

However, is it possible to feed the gpg-agent the passphrase beforehand and then have emacs use this, but not to prompt for a passphrase if the agent doesn't already have this info?

What settings would allow this to work with `notmuch.el` and `EasyPG`?

Or, are there alternative methods of caching the passphrase which would achieve the same effect, but may have security problems (which is the reason gpg-agent exists in the first place)?

Comment: should this be moved to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Sure -- It's on here because I don't think emacs.stackexchange.com existed when I asked the question  :)

Answer (score 5):

THIS! -> https://github.com/ecraven/pinentry-emacs

You'll have to do some wrenching, but using this thing worked for me. Put the script there into a directory in your `PATH` and then add the following entry to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
pinentry-program <path-to-pinentry-emacs>/pinentry-emacs
```

Then reload the agent:

```
$ echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
```

Works like a dream for me :)

Comment: What happens if you're outside of emacs and need to enter a pin? (Is there a way to use pinentry-curses when asked from outside emacs, and pinentry-emacs when asked from inside emacs?)

Comment: gpg is supposed to be able to fall back to other pinentries if it can't access emacs pinentry, but I have emacs running on a daemon, so it never falls back for me :( When I use this, I must either not run emacs as a daemon (something I haven't tried), or I must have an emacs window open so I can put in my password

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, if you have a fairly recent pinentry/gpg2 (tested with 0.9.7 and 2.1.11 respectively on Arch Linux), is to use http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/pinentry.html.

Install `pinentry` from `M-x list-packages`, then put

```
allow-emacs-pinentry
```

in your `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and put

```
(setenv "INSIDE_EMACS" (format "%s,comint" emacs-version))
(pinentry-start)
```

in your `.emacs.d/init.el`. 
I had to put the setenv in there because, although INSIDE_EMACS is set when running `M-x shell`, it's not set when simply opening a `.gpg` file.

Now gpg-agent uses the regular curses version from the terminal, and from within Emacs it uses `read-passwd` (which hides the characters from prompt and from `view-lossage`).

---

EDIT: It seems the Debian package has a patch to remove Emacs support, so for now this solution only works for other distros / people prepared to compile pinentry themselves.

Comment: The pinentry package help says:
"NOTE: As of June 2015, this feature requires newer versions of GnuPG (2.1.5+) and Pinentry (not yet released, possibly 0.9.5+).  For details, see the discussion on gnupg-devel mailing list:
<https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2015-May/029875.html>."

So I've not managed to get this to work yet but shall try again soon!

Comment: yeah, you'd need Ubuntu Xenial or Debian Stretch it seems (or Arch of course)

Comment: Edited answer; it seems Debian's pinentry package removed the Emacs support (which is included in Arch and Fedora, however). See https://bugs.gnupg.org/gnupg/msg6623 (and note that https://github.com/ecraven/pinentry-emacs confusingly is a completely different program).

Comment: Using GuixSD 0.11.0 with gpg 2.1.13 and emacs 25.1.1, the pinentry emacs package is "built-in". Also, there is no need to set the INSIDE_EMACS variable anymore, it just works, after setting the "allow-emacs-pinentry" option and `pkill gpg-agent` so that it restarts with the new setting the next time!

Answer (score 3):

In 2021, you can use the setting `pinentry-mode loopback` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` after setting up your gpg-agent and using `allow-loopback-entry` in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`